# Performance difference between inlined hashCode and Objects.hash

Tags: java, hashcode

A general question (probably answered before, but not found by me).

What should I prefer: the Josh Bloch implementation of hash code directly im my class or delegation to the method `Objects.hash(...)`.

Pros for Josh Bloch variant:

- Autogeneration in Eclipse
- Faster (?)

Pros for `Objects.hash`

- Quick hand-written implementation
- Non-Verbouse

And yes, I know that the `Objects.hash` uses the formula of Josh Bloch internally.

Now my question: is direct implementation of Josh Bloch formula in my class **significantly** faster than delegation to `Objects.hash`? Because the `Objects.hash` requres the creation of additional array for submitting of parameters and boxing of primitives. But I also known, that JVM provides much of "magic" for performance optimization, so my assumption may be incorrect (for example cache for primitives can improve boxing speed).

The same question for equals: should I use autogenerated method, or should I delegate to `Arrays.equals`

A little bit code, to demonstrate how I would implement these methods using delegation.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyObject {

    private int field1;
    private String field2;
    private long field3;

    // use special method to grant that the both equals and hashCode 
    // are changed when a field is added or removed.
    private Object[] data() {
        return new Object[] {field1, field2, field3};
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof MyObject) {
            return Arrays.equals(data(), ((MyObject) obj).data());
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(data());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any test data that answers it.  I'm suspicious of such tests anyway; they're usually written badly.  I would be surprised to learn that such a nano optimization mattered.  I would vote for the most straightforward, readable implementation that met the "Effective Java" standards.  I would also avoid adding another dependency.  IntelliJ generates equals and hashCode implementations that are readable without dependencies.  I prefer those.

Comment: @duffymo The `Objects` is a standard Java SE class. And as I said, it uses Josh Bloch hashCode implementation internally.

Comment: I haven't started using it, so I'm unfamiliar.  Thank you for the heads up.  If it uses Joshua Bloch implementation internally, what is your concern?  Just performance?  It should be possible to look at the source code and judge it for yourself.

Comment: @duffymo The problem is that the call of these methods requires allocation of memory for some objects, that I cannot estimate.

Comment: I don't recall the Bloch implementations of equals or hashCode requiring additional memory.  Your example calls Arrays methods, not Objects.  Why is that?

Comment: I think you would need to hit some very special edge-case usage scenarios for this to have any meaningful performance impact.

Comment: @duffymo: I think by "extra memory" he means the intermediate wrapper created by `data()` -- and as he mentioned as well, the JIT can probably optimize that away, but even if it doesn't ...

Comment: @Thilo Thanks. So you think, I can ignore the memory allocation overhead?

Comment: Put together a JMH test and post results. The answer to what you ask is very different depending on exact details. Even memory can be a problem -- e.g., when running in a JMH, GC has an easy job discarding all those extra objects and you might not see any performance decrease, but when put into a large codebase, it suddenly might be difficult for GC, and it would have a major impact. Rule of thumb is, you should make hashCode and equals as simple as you can, and they should not allocate memory.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy As Donald Knuth stated "premature optimization is the root of all evil". I would focus on writing clean code which is easy to read at a first place. Think about optimizations later. In case when optimization is needed, probably you will have more significant performance gain if you take a look at different areas of your application.